# How to remove or hide the label of a Toggle in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm looking for a way to remove the label of a `Toggle` in SwiftUI...

I have tried with `ToggleStyle` but it does not seems to be the right way:

```
Toggle(isOn: $isBlinky) {
    Text("DO NOT DISPLAY").color(.red)
}
.toggleStyle(.switch)
```

As the label seems to be included in the type itself (`struct Toggle<Label>`) there may be no way to only have the switch alone...

By the way if I use `Text("")` and then `scaledToFit()` the switch is still a bit on the right and not really centered...

Anyway if someone has an idea!

**PS:** While waiting for a solution, I wrapped a good old `UISwitch`, but that's not the idea...

```
struct Switch : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isOn : Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISwitch {
        let uiView = UISwitch()
        uiView.addTarget(
            context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(Coordinator.didChange(sender:)),
            for: .valueChanged)

        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISwitch, context: Context) {
        uiView.isOn = isOn
    }

    // MARK:- Coordinator

    func makeCoordinator() -> Switch.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: Switch

        init(_ control: Switch) {
            self.control = control
        }

        @objc func didChange(sender: UISwitch) {
            control.isOn = sender.isOn
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## SwiftUI 1.0

### Hide the label/title with the labelsHidden Modifier

This is how it should be done.

```
Toggle("Turn alarm on", isOn: $isToggleOn)
    .labelsHidden() // Hides the label/title
```

*Note: Even though the label is hidden, you should still add one for accessibility purposes.*

### Example:

[image: Toggle Example with no Label]

Comment: Simple and easy workaround, thanks. But are the 5px constant with all kind of accessibility font size settings?

Comment: @Zaphod, I tested it out. I added `.border(Color.red)` to make sure it is centered. Then I ran it and adjusted the Environment Overrides for Dynamic Type from lowest to highest and it remained consistent.

Comment: Well, that's a good solution, even if I really dislike the magic numbers `5` and `25` that could change in the future... Well, while waiting for Swift UI 2.0, or an option yet to be discovered, I will grant you the answer, congratulations... ;)

Comment: Hey @Zaphod, I found out the right way to do this and updated my answer so you now need no magic numbers!

Comment: Annoyingly even when using `.labelsHidden()`, the view still seems to occupy the extra space that it would need for a label, rather than just fitting the actual toggle. If anyone like me also needs this space for other content, I found a combination of the `.labelsHidden()` modifier and `.frame(.frame(width: 25).offset(x: -15)` works alright.

Comment: @WillAlexander I'm using Xcode 12.4 and there is no additional space around the toggle.

Answer (score 6):

You can hide label with the .labelsHidden() modifier:

```
Toggle(isOn: $switchValue) {}
      .labelsHidden()
```

Comment: Indeed, but it was not available when the question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

This option is very suitable if you want to hide the display of text.

```
    Toggle(isOn: $isActive) {
        Label("This will hide this text", systemImage: "eye.fill")
            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        }
```

Comment: This would probably benefit from a little explanation rather than *just* presenting code

Comment: The question was how to hide the label of the `Toggle` itself. This answer does not adress that. Recommend deletion.

Answer (score 0):

To customise a `Toggle`, you can roll your own `ToggleStyle`.

```swift
struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {

    func body(configuration: Toggle<Self.Label>) -> Text {
        // Define look and feel for the toggle
        Text("Text toggle (?)")
    }

    typealias Body = Text

}

extension StaticMember where Base: ToggleStyle {

    static var custom: CustomToggleStyle.Member {
        return .init(CustomToggleStyle())
    }

}
```

and use it like this

```swift
.toggleStyle(.custom)
```

This seems to be the way of doing it, **but the API is not ready yet**!

`configuration` doesn't expose the values we need to build a toggle.

By `dump`ing it, I can see it has a few useful properties...

```
SwiftUI.Toggle<SwiftUI.ToggleStyleLabel>
  - label: SwiftUI.ToggleStyleLabel
  - state: SwiftUI.ToggleState.off
  - setOn: (Function)
```

...but they seem to be private.

I will update this answer once I find out more.

Comment: Thank you, this was not the question, but it's another way of doing it... Unfortunately this way you loose everything that comes with the Toggle (Catalyst portability with macOS style, and so on...)

Comment: Well thanks for the update... But indeed, it seems that there's no solution today without hacking in a way or another...

Answer (score 0):

Not being a big fan of "magic numbers", I tend to go out of my way to avoid them.  After a lot of debugging (including UI Testing View Dumps), the culprit is SwiftUI's implementation of DefaultToggleStyle().  The actual space taken up by the (non-existent) label for that style cannot be eliminated and, as we've seen, must be manually adjusted.   However, if you create a custom toggle style, you can eliminate the need for a shim to "adjust" the position of the Toggle. The key is to totally eliminate the label from the Custom Toggle Style's View. Then, you need to create Views for both the "on" and "off" states of the toggle and animate the transition.  Basically you would have to re-implement the Switch Control from scratch.

I updated the example below to show how perfect alignment can be achieved given appropriate graphics. The Capsule's and Toggle's do line up exactly. Otherwise, the only other choice is to hope the magic numbers don't change too often.

BTW, the size of the Switch in the default style is 57 wide and 31 high.

```
import SwiftUI

extension Set {
    subscript(member: Element) -> Bool {
        get {
            return contains(member)
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                insert(member)
                print("Selecting: \(member)")
            } else {
                remove(member)
                print("Deselecting: \(member)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items:[String] = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]
    @State var selection: Set<String> = Set<String>()
    var body: some View {
        List(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
            VStack {
                Capsule().frame(width: 50, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Toggle(item, isOn: self.$selection[item])
//                        .frame(width: 25)
//                        .offset(x: -5) // Center toggle
                        .toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle())
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: CustomToggleStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            if configuration.isOn {
                Button(action: { configuration.isOn.toggle() } )
                { Capsule().frame(width: 50, height: 30).foregroundColor(.red) }
            } else {
                Button(action: { configuration.isOn.toggle() } )
                { Capsule().frame(width: 50, height: 30).foregroundColor(.green) }
            }
//            configuration.label
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this update. Unfortunately it still acts like there are two views (the `EmptyView` and the toggle button). For instance if you create a screen with only a toggle : `Toggle("", isOn: $blinky).toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle())` the button is right aligned instead of being centered as it would be expected.

Comment: In fact it leads to the same problem discovered with `Text("")`, even with `scaledToFit()` it leaves a small space on the leadingside...

Comment: I also discovered the same problem with NavigationLink yesterday. Adding a Spacer() before and after the Toggle and also setting the Toggle's frame size to zero seems to do the trick.  Everything is now centered.

Comment: I should also point out that  this solution also works without a CustomToggleStyle.  Just set the frame size and add the spacers to the Toggle inside the List item.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not centered, if you look closely. To be sure, just add a small `Capsule().frame(width: 50, height: 30, alignment: .center)` just above your toggle.

Comment: Looks like it's a choice between a totally custom Toggle style or hard coding constants to adjust a default style that could change in the future.